# Django webpack_loader: `Regex` Undefined?

Tags: python, django, webpack, webpack-loader, django-webpack-loader

I've updated a Django app to Python 3.9 and Django 4.0, and I'm getting an error on launch:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I tracked it down to this function in `python3.9/site-packages/webpack_loader/loader.py`:

```
def filter_chunks(self, chunks):
    filtered_chunks = []

    for chunk in chunks:
        ignore = any(regex.match(chunk)
                     for regex in self.config['ignores'])
        if not ignore:
            filtered_chunks.append(chunk)

    return filtered_chunks
```

On the line `ignore = any(regex.match(chunk)...`, `regex` is undefined.

[image]

I ran `brew upgrade python`, but Homebrew said:

> Warning: python 3.9.13_1 already installed

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a joke of your IDE. Could you try retyping `regex` manually in both places? Maybe it is whitespace issue or something similar. `regex` variable is 100% fine here, it is defined inside generator. Also could you running from terminal without IDE instead?

Comment: Okay I think you're right. If I ignore that I find a much more solvable-looking error. Thanks! If you post that as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.